# media queries of inner content not responding on changing width of containing div

Tags: jquery-animate, width, media-queries

i am loading the content inside div **#iframe** using jquery **$.get**
i want to resize the content according to media queries on clicking top buttons,mobile, ipad,desktop
kindly visit below link
http://designgear.in/test/
js used

```
    $(".mobile_scale").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#iframe").animate({
                    "width": "320px"
                }, 400);
                 setTimeout(function() {
                    adjustIframeheight();
                }, 500);
            });
            $(".tablet_scale").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#iframe").animate({
                    "width": "480px",
                    marginLeft: "auto",
                    marginLeft: "auto"
                }, 400);
                 setTimeout(function() {
                    adjustIframeheight();
                }, 500);
            });
            $(".desktop_scale").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#iframe").animate({
                    "width": "600px"
                }, 400);
                 setTimeout(function() {
                    adjustIframeheight();
                }, 500);
            });
```